# Material-UI grid values overflow

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI with Typescript and React and I added a couple of new values for theme spacing.
Now when I use `<Grid container spacing={new value}>` it throws the following error in the console:

```
Material-UI: The value provided (9) overflows.
The supported values are: [4,8,10,14,16,24,32,40].
9 > 7, you need to add the missing values.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to reference these values by their index. In this case `7` would use the value `40` and that's where your array ends.